# ASPNETCOMPILER: error Object Reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I am having this error when I am trying to build a web project in VS2012 and VS2013.

I have done various suggestions from my research but there is no luck. (removing *.compiled files, etc.)

The project is done in VS2012 and I am trying to build it in VS2013 update 4.

it seems to work with my colleagues local machine using VS2012.

[image: error message when build]

Any help would be appreciated. thanks!

Edited:

The error message is:

> ASPNETCOMPILER: error ASPRUNTIME: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

and there is no more description, to there is no clue at all.

Comment: Can't see the screen shot.  Post the text in the post......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after wasting precious hours, I was able to resolve the problem by deleting the "obj" folder.

Answer (score 0):

Excluding the bin folder from the Project worked for me. But still cant figure out how the issue originated and the source of the issue. Well, as of now it worked for me and saved a lot of time. Hope it might help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Cleared out the bin folder, restored Nuget packages and built to regenerate it. This solved the problem.  I assume some of the work I had done with versions of third party packages had left something bad in the bin folder, which didn't prevent a compile, but prevented generating the temp obj\Debug\Package in WebSitePublish folder.